# Reconnect to NFC TAG without reintroduction

Tags: android, nfc, reconnect

I've been struggling now for a long time to find out if it is possible to trigger `tag_discovered` without moving an NFC-tag away and then back. My findings show that on some devices it is possible by simply closing the NfcA connection using the following command `nfcA.close()`. It seems like different manufacturers implements this in different ways (?).

Are there other ways to destroy the NFC-field between the device and the TAG?

I have also tried disabling NfcAdapter and NfcManager. Which also seems to work on some devices but not all:

```kotlin
// Disable
nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
nfcManager.defaultAdapter.disableReaderMode(this)

// Enable 
val option = Bundle()
option.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 2000)
nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, nfcManager, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, option)
```

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason to reconnect? If you did not close the connection you would not need to reconnect.

Comment: I'm performing a command that requires me to re-detect the TAG.

Comment: Not sure why performing multiple commands forces you to reconnect, I've issued 100's of commands to a card without reconnecting.

Comment: It might help if you specified the Tag types you are working with and the specifics of the command that is forcing you to reconnect as I suspect that this is not a standard command or a fully compliant Tag.

Comment: I can't see why this is relevant to the original question? The question is simple, is it possible to somehow destroy the NFC field between the NFC Tag and the device without reintroducing it physically. It's an NfcA TAG, thats all I can say.

Comment: The reason is to see if there is a work around for this behaviour that not to the NFC Forum standards, as the field is not something even the NFC service controls as the secure element might be using it and other Android Services like Beam might be using it. You can usually turn the field off by turning off NFC in the system settings, but usually you cannot do this programmatically, the user has to do it.

Comment: Turning off NFC programmatically requires rooting the device which is not an option. I'm looking for a solution similar but I guess its impossible to achieve. I have written the same app on iOS where I am able to re-detect without moving the TAG away physically. Frustrating.

Comment: My guess is that you don't actually need to turn the field off but just need to get the Tag to the ISO14443-3 HALT state and then bring it back to ACTIVE state, but that is unknown. Again sending the  low level ISO14443-3 commands of HLTA and WUPA to do this is problematic on Android as it is not designed for the user to send these commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Andrew.

> My guess is that you don't actually need to turn the field off but just need to get the Tag to the ISO14443-3 HALT state and then bring it back to ACTIVE state, but that is unknown. Again sending the low level ISO14443-3 commands of HLTA and WUPA to do this is problematic on Android as it is not designed for the user to send these commands.

Looking closer on the ISO14443-3 standard and the HALT command I finally found a solution. Running the command below causes a `TagLostException` which in turn makes the `onTagDiscovered` method run. So by using HALT I can rediscover TAGs without a physical re-introduction.

```java
byte[] HaltCMD = {0x35, 0x30, 0x30,0x30, 0x00};
```